# MiniFilter driver. Filter attaching problems

Tags: winapi, driver, volume, minifilter

I'm developing a miniFilter driver and took the Microsoft's SwapBuffers 
miniFilter as example.
An InstaceSetup routin by default is attaching to all volumes. But I don't want 
to attach to all of them, only to some choosen...

I tried to set "NULL" instead of "InstanceSetup" in "FLT_REGISTRATION 
FilterRegistration" and then to call "FltAttachVolume" in the "DriverEntry" 
routin. I've done the following:

PFLT_VOLUME vol;
UNICODE_STRING vname;
....
RtlInitUnicodeString(&vname, L"E:\");
FltGetVolumeFromName(gFilterHandle, &vname, &vol);
...
FltAttachVolume(gFilterHandle, vol, NULL, NULL);
...

When i tried to call FltAttachVolume with the "NULL" 3-d parameter 
(PCUNICODE_STRING InstanceName) i received a 
**"STATUS_FLT_INSTANCE_NAME_COLLISION"** error.

If i call FltAttachVolume with a "NOT NULL" 3-d parameter, such as a 
"UniqueInstaceName" it returns me **"-2145452013"**.

I'm receiving the same errors, when i,m trying to attach a volume, using a 
FilterAttach routine from my User application, like this:

...
driver.driverName = L"swapBuffers";
...
LPCWSTR vname = L"F:\";
...
FilterAttach(driver.driverName, vname, NULL, NULL, NULL);

With "NULL" 3-d  parameter (LPCWSTR lpInstanceName): 
**"ERROR_FLT_INSTANCE_NAME_COLLISION"**

With "NOT-NULL": **"-2145452013"**.

In MiniSpy miniFilter there is a User application, and the routine FilterAttach 
is used. I tried to call this routine in my application the same way - no 
results.

Finally, i changed the swapBuffers inf-file:

- there was no DefaultInstance parameter, i set it: "SwapBuffers - Top 
  Instance".
- also i copied this from the MiniSpy inf-file:

  [MiniFilter.AddRegistry]
  HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance2.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance2.Altitude%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance2.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance2.Flags%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance3.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance3.Altitude%
  HKR,"Instances\"%Instance3.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance3.Flags%

  .............
  Instance1.Name          = "SwapBuffers - Middle Instance"
  Instance1.Altitude      = "370000"
  Instance1.Flags         = 0x1          ; Suppress automatic attachments
  Instance2.Name          = "SwapBuffers - Bottom Instance"
  Instance2.Altitude      = "361000"
  Instance2.Flags         = 0x1          ; Suppress automatic attachments
  Instance3.Name          = "SwapBuffers - Top Instance"
  Instance3.Altitude      = "385100"
  Instance3.Flags         = 0x1          ; Suppress automatic attachments

changing the flags to 0x1 to suppress automatic attachments.
And only installing my SwapBuffers miniFilter through this Inf file, i received 
**"STATUS_SUCCESS"** from FltAttachVolume routine in my driver. But it isn't really 
attaching to the disk...

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instance1.Flags = 0x1
```

That is fine.
I have somewhat similar code and that works fine.

```
status = FltRegisterFilter( DriverObject,
                            &FilterRegistration,
                            &gFilterHandle );

FLT_ASSERT( NT_SUCCESS( status ) );

if (NT_SUCCESS( status )) {
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
    UNICODE_STRING uniString;

    status = FltBuildDefaultSecurityDescriptor(&sd,
        FLT_PORT_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniString, PORT_NAME);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa,
        &uniString,
        OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE | OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE,
        NULL,
        sd);

    status = FltCreateCommunicationPort(gFilterHandle,
        &gServerPort,
        &oa,
        NULL,
        Connect,
        Disconnect,
        Message,
        1);

    FltFreeSecurityDescriptor(sd);

    BREAK_HERE(); // DbgBreak() macro

    //
    //  Start filtering i/o
    //

    status = FltStartFiltering(gFilterHandle);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        FltUnregisterFilter(gFilterHandle);
    }
    else {
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniString, L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1");
        PFLT_VOLUME vol;
        FltGetVolumeFromName(gFilterHandle, &uniString, &vol);
        status = FltAttachVolume(gFilterHandle, vol, NULL, NULL);
        // status == 0x0 at that point and the mini filter is attached to the Volume
    }
}
```

I normally attach to all volumes but I wanted to try attaching to a single volume and it works fine.

Comment: I have tried this but got "the system cannot find the file specified" and immediately blue screen...

Comment: Sorry the message is "because it has not finished initializing (FltStartFiltering has not been called)" and immediately blue screen...